# mysql remove and update the duplicate with the quantity of the original

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

add qty

12, george st(add) 1(qty)

12, george st(add) 1(qty)

12, george st(add) 1(qty)

i would like to make it into

12, george st(add) 3(qty)

thanks!

```
SELECT DISTINCT(add) AS add, COUNT(add) AS count
FROM ex
GROUP BY add
HAVING count > 1
```

i have few hundred thousands adds and many are duplicates. i have to remove the duplicates and leave the original and update quantity of the original.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I would insert first into temporary table, then delete those rows and insert from temporary table to original table

Answer (score 0):

You mean like

```
SELECT add, SUM(qty) AS quantity
FROM ex
GROUP BY add
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with the totals:

```
CREATE TABLE ex2 AS
SELECT add, SUM(qty) AS qty
FROM ex
GROUP BY add
```

Then remove the old table and rename the new table.

Comment: i have few hundred thousands adds and many are duplicates. i have to remove the duplicates and leave the original and update quantity of the original.

Comment: @vinz: You want to remove the duplicates and leave the original and update quantity of the original. You can first create a new table using the query `CREATE TABLE ex2 AS
SELECT add, SUM(qty) AS qty
FROM ex
GROUP BY add`. Then remove the old table, and rename the new table.